# Removing wires from this kind of lightbulb socket

Tags: electrical, wiring, installation, light-bulb

I'm trying to uninstall/install cables from/to lightbulb sockets as shown below. The cables go into two of the small round holes as shown in the second picture. There is no obvious way to squeeze, clamp, screw or turn the cables or parts of the sockets. I assume one would need to stick something into any of the other holes to release an internal clamp, but I wasn't very successful in doing so. This is in Switzerland.
Any ideas on how to proceed or what this type of socket is called?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you sacrifice one of these or buy one specially to break apart and dissect?

Answer (score 4):

We have a similar idea in North America.

Usually just use a tiny screwdriver to push in a small hole nearby to release the wire.

It should be the tiny hole on the outside edge.

The type here is not well liked by electricians(cause problems) only by installers.

The cheap North American type is usually consider single use only. No one should trust the spring holder to last past the first time use.

Do not know the quality of the ones you have, but if they are not expensive(to you) might just use new ones. Just cut the wire at the edge of the old ones(with power off).

Comment: Or look down into the other holes and see if there is an obvious pry point?

Answer (score 4):

Logic would seem to dictate you push a screwdriver between the visible pins in the inner holes, which would release pressure outwards from the wire clamps.

[image]

Not my favourite type of fixing, I've got to say.